# Convert Julia array to dataframe

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

I have an array X that I'd like to convert to a dataframe. Upon recommendation from the web, I tried converting to a dataframe and get the following error.

`julia> y=convert(DataFrame,x)
ERROR:`convert`has no method matching convert(::Type{DataFrame}, ::Array{Float64,2})
 in convert at base.jl:13`

When I try `DataFrame(x)`, the conversion works but i get a complaint that the conversion is deprecated.

`julia> DataFrame(x)
WARNING: DataFrame(::Matrix, ::Vector)) is deprecated, use convert(DataFrame, Matrix) instead in DataFrame at /Users/Matthew/.julia/v0.3/DataFrames/src/deprecated.jl:54 (repeats 2 times)`

Is there another method I should be aware of to keep my code consistent?

EDIT:
Julia 0.3.2,
DataFrames 0.5.10
OSX 10.9.5

```
julia> x=rand(4,4)
4x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.467882   0.466358  0.28144   0.0151388
 0.22354    0.358616  0.669564  0.828768
 0.475064   0.187992  0.584741  0.0543435
 0.0592643  0.345138  0.704496  0.844822

julia> convert(DataFrame,x)
ERROR: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{DataFrame}, ::Array{Float64,2}) in convert at base.jl:13
```

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> x = rand(4, 4)
4x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.790912  0.0367989  0.425089  0.670121
 0.243605  0.62487    0.582498  0.302063
 0.785159  0.0083891  0.881153  0.353925
 0.618127  0.827093   0.577815  0.488565

julia> convert(DataFrame, x)
4x4 DataFrame
| Row | x1       | x2        | x3       | x4       |
|-----|----------|-----------|----------|----------|
| 1   | 0.790912 | 0.0367989 | 0.425089 | 0.670121 |
| 2   | 0.243605 | 0.62487   | 0.582498 | 0.302063 |
| 3   | 0.785159 | 0.0083891 | 0.881153 | 0.353925 |
| 4   | 0.618127 | 0.827093  | 0.577815 | 0.488565 |
```

Are you trying something different?

If that doesn't work try posting a bit more code we can help you better.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is the first thing that comes up when you google, for more recent versions of `DataFrames.jl`, you can just use the `DataFrame()` function now:

```
julia> x = rand(4,4)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.920406  0.738911  0.994401  0.9954
 0.18791   0.845132  0.277577  0.231483
 0.361269  0.918367  0.793115  0.988914
 0.725052  0.962762  0.413111  0.328261

julia> DataFrame(x, :auto)
4×4 DataFrame
 Row │ x1        x2        x3        x4       
     │ Float64   Float64   Float64   Float64  
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.920406  0.738911  0.994401  0.9954
   2 │ 0.18791   0.845132  0.277577  0.231483
   3 │ 0.361269  0.918367  0.793115  0.988914
   4 │ 0.725052  0.962762  0.413111  0.328261
```

Comment: And `DataFrame(x, ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])` to set your own column names

Answer (score 4):

I've been confounded by the same issue a number of times, and eventually realized  the issue is  often related to the format of the array, and is easily resolved by simply transposing the array prior to conversion.

In short, I recommend:

```
julia> convert(DataFrame, x')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# convert a Matrix{Any} with a header row of col name strings to a DataFrame
# e.g. mat2df(["a" "b" "c"; 1 2 3; 4 5 6])

mat2df(mat) = convert(DataFrame,Dict(mat[1,:],
                     [mat[2:end,i] for i in 1:size(mat,2)]))

# convert a Matrix{Any} (mat) and a list of col name strings (headerstrings) 
# to a DataFrame, e.g. matnms2df([1 2 3;4 5 6], ["a","b","c"])

matnms2df(mat, headerstrs) = convert(DataFrame,
    Dict(zip(headerstrs,[mat[:,i] for i in 1:size(mat,2)])))
```

Comment: This no longer works under Julia v0.6.0 because you can't construct a Dict this way anymore. Replacing the `Dict()` calls with `Dict(zip())` seems to work.

Comment: Attention that if the Matrix to conver has mixed types, the converted DataFrame has all Any's (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487261/how-to-convert-a-mixed-type-matrix-to-dataframe-in-julia-recognising-the-column/46488660#46488660)

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but with the update to the DataFrame() function, I created a custom function that would take a matrix (e.g. an XLSX imported dataset) and convert it into a DataFrame using the first row as column headers. Saves me a ton of time and, hopefully, it helps you too.

```
function MatrixToDataFrame(mat)
    DF_mat = DataFrame(
        mat[2:end, 1:end],
        string.(mat[1, 1:end])
    )
    return DF_mat
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found this online and honestly felt dumb.

```
using CSV
WhatIWant = DataFrame(WhatIHave)
```

this was adapted from an R guide, but it works so heck

Answer (score 1):

```
DataFrame([1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12], :auto)
```

This works as per >? DataFrame