# How to convert in Julia a Matrix ( Array{Any,2} ) with headers to a DataFrame without loosing column order?

Tags: dataframe, julia

how can I convert a Julia matrix with headers on the first row as DataFrame ?

I did read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284301/1586860), that covers the same problem, but it gives me an error in the Dict constructor.

ok, I wrote my own implementation (that should work):

```
m = [ ['c',1,2] ['a',3,4] ['b',5,6] ]
3×3 Array{Any,2}:
  'c'   'a'   'b'
 1     3     5   
 2     4     6   
df = convert(DataFrame, Dict([(ch,m[2:end,cix]) for (cix,ch) in enumerate(m[1,:])]))
2×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a │ b │ c │
├─────┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 3 │ 5 │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 4 │ 6 │ 2 │
```

But it still uses dictionary and so original column order is lost. And I have a guess it may be very slow!

So, how could I transform a matrix in a dataframe using the first row as the df header without loosing the column order ?

Comment: Just replace `Dict(...)` with `OrderedDict(...)` (OrderedDict is in DataStructures, but possibly already imported, otherwise do `using DataStructures` first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution without a dictionary:

```
DataFrame(Any[@view m[2:end, i] for i in 1:size(m, 2)], Symbol.(m[1, :]))
```

But really, if you could skip the header and load it separately, you would get a much more efficient structure than `Matrix{Any}` (and a slightly simpler code here).

Comment: How? Maybe you can make your question more specific?